# Teradata - find a value from preceding second row

Tags: sql, teradata

```
WITH data (cust, amt, rnk) AS (
VALUES(a, 10, 1),
    (a, 5, 2),
    (a, 15, 3),
    (b, 20, 1),
    (b, 30, 2),
    (c, 3, 1))
```

I have the data like above. I need to find the amt for each cust where either if the  max(rnk) = 1 then amt from that row. Else amt from rnk = 2.
So the result would be as below:

```
a,5,2
b,30,2
c,3,1
```

I can't seem to get to that. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean if the max(amt) is rnk 1?

Comment: If there the max(rnk) =1 then amt for that row.
But if there are more than 1 rows for that customer, then the amount for second row whatever that may be.

So I would have a case statement.

   Case max(rnk) =  1 then amt
   else -- this is the question
   end

Comment: can there be deleted rows so that rnk is not consecutive?

Comment: rnk is row number so it is consecutive. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Teradata supports CTE:

```
with max_rank as (
  select cust, max(rnk) as m_rank
  from data
  where rnk in (1,2)
  group by cust
  )
select d.cust, d.amt, d.rnk
from data d
join max_rank r
  on d.cust = r.cust
 and d.rnk = r.m_rank
```

| cust | amt | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 2 |
| b | 30 | 2 |
| c | 3 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WjQVcwkJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the matching row using rank/row_number

```
select *
from data
where rnk <= 2
qualify 
   rank()
   over (partition by cust
         order by rnk desc) = 1
```